# How could I set up a changing range (constraint) of weights in training process. The platform is Keras or TensorFlow

Tags: keras

How could I set up a changing range (constraint) of weights in the training process? The platform is Keras or TensorFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look here : https://keras.io/constraints/.

I think that you are looking for `MinMaxNorm()`.

```
keras.constraints.MinMaxNorm(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0)
```

In your code, you would do this:

```
from keras.constraints import max_norm
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_constraint=min_max_norm(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0)))
```

I would recommend using `from tensorflow.keras.constraints import max_norm`, as the tendency is to switch to Keras inside TensorFlow instead of plain Keras.